# Change upstream of local (hg-git) clone from (github) original to fork

Tags: github, mercurial, hg-git

I discovered an OSS project I've contributed to had moved to github.  I installed hg-git and cloned a local repo from the git:// URL; then I made changes.

I then realized I really wanted my own github fork, so I made one; but I haven't been able to figure out quite how to switch my existing local repo.  I've changed the local repo settings to use the git:// URL of my fork, and it can pull; but I can't push my changes up.  It tells me to use the https:// URL, but when I make that change, I can neither pull nor push -- I get an error 406, "not acceptable."

The work done in the local repo is minimal, so I can redo it, but it'd be simpler if the local repo and my fork could just connect now.

**UPDATE**

I've installed Github for Windows so I could manage the SSH key.  It generated a key (github_rsa) and attached it to my Github account.

I edited the hgrc file and added a `[ui]ssh=` setting pointing to the local git 'ssh' command (buried down in `%APPDATA%\Local\Github`).

With this, if I go into a "git-shell" window, which I guess spawns ssh-agent, then I can enter commands such as "hg incoming" and the connection is made.  So I've got the remote repo URL right, and within the git-shell ecosystem, I've got the SSH keys set up right.

From a regular CMD.EXE window, the same command yields "Permission denied (publickey)".  From TortoiseHg, the same error appears when I try an "incoming" action.  I'd prefer to keep using TortoiseHg, but I'm not sure how to get it to use SSH.

**FINAL UPDATE**

For some reason, TortoisePlink doesn't want to play with github's SSH server, at least not with the Github-for-Windows-generated key.  So I still have Github for Windows installed (not necessarily a bad thing, but superfluous to what I wanted to do).

To get hg and TortoiseHg to connect, I had to modify my project settings:

```
[ui]
ssh = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\<salt>\bin\ssh -i %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\github_rsa
```

That is: point to the SSH command, installed with portable GitHub, and specify the github-generated key on the command line.  With this configuration, I don't need ssh-agent to be running.

Comment: You should be able to push using to the new `git+ssh://<github_url>`. Can you post the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push via ssh, meaning you need to push via:

```
hg push git+ssh://git@github.com/<login>/<repo>
```

Note the usage of `git@` instead of your login in the first part of the URL. This actually matters; the server will figure out your credentials via the supplied SSH key.

You may also have to add your ssh key to your GitHub account first (per [step 4 of this page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account)).

This assumes that you created a fork of the original GitHub repository via the GitHub UI; pushing to an empty repository with hg-git may require additional steps.

Comment: Your answer has helped, but I'm not quite where I want to be; please see the update.

Comment: I don't work on Windows myself, but Bitbucket has help files [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial) and [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Configure+multiple+SSH+identities+for+TortoiseHg) that tell you how to setup ssh on Windows for Mercurial and TortoiseHg, respectively (just switch out bitbucket.org for github.com in the URLs). To add a generated public SSH key to GitHub through the web UI, see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account).

Comment: I'm granting the answer, but I had to do a lot of figuring stuff out to finally get to using my toolset with github.